# iOS VOIP notification Linphone

Tags: ios, objective-c, linphone, pushkit, linphone-sdk

I have set up the latest linphone iOS code (version 3.16.6) and I am able to make audio and video calls but if my app is in background or killed, not getting calls.

Please guide me in details that what I have to do to get the calls even when app is in background or killed.

Please let me know if there is server interaction part also there.

Answer (score 0):

You have to wake up your application with voip-notification, before receiving call on background.

- So you can implement your solution which send notification before every call. Notification wake an app and app receive the call

  - You can use callkit for UI, but callkit itself doesn't handle any background or voip work.
- Use some working solution for example FlexiSip from Belledonne

  - http://www.linphone.org/technical-corner/flexisip/overview
  - FlexiSip have builtin support for iOS push notification, but you will need to generate certificates and do some server work :)

**EDIT**
Voip notification process.

Before every SIP Invite you have send voip notification to target device. Voip notification wake application which will be ready for accepting SIP call.

I'm not sure if you use proxy or if you making just direct calls. If you are using proxy you can try FlexiSIP which should handle this logic for you (I didn't tried). Of course you will need to provide your voip certificates to it.

If you making direct calls without SIP proxy, source application should call same API of some web service which send voip notification for target device (For example Houston API). And after you can send SIP invite from source to target application.

Comment: Could you please write down the steps in detail?  That would be more helpful.

Comment: Sure I can. But what you mean? Steps for process with voip notifications?

Comment: yes.

I have also created voip certificates and tested with Houston and if sending voip notification through it, getting call even if app is closed.
Do I need to host this certificate on server or elsewhere and need to call an API from app to trigger the notification on another device?

Please guide.

Comment: I edited original reply, write if is sufficient for you.